# Deployment options of SPFx app without tenant permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I used to work with Sharepoint 2013 OnProm with Content Editor webparts from where I can just embed an HTML file and some JS scripts.

I'm now looking at Sharepoint Online in my organization. I'm a Site Collection Admin, but I don't have tenant permissions (which is reserved for a very small number of people inside my company's IT team).

I looked at the way to create webparts with SPFx, but it seems the deployment always ends with publishing the webpart to the Tenant App Store... Which I don't have access to.

There is no Content Editor webpart in my Site Collection (maybe it hasn't been activated by my IT?!), and if I upload an .html file in a doc library, I cannot open it directly (it will force a download of the file).

**I'd like to create a Single Page Application, or at least a webpart. But without Tenant permissions, what are my options here? Knowing that I cannot ask to my IT team to change anything at this stage (I cannot request Site Collection App store, or to enable Content Editor).**

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Site Collection App store would be your only option, but as noted, must be enabled by someone holding the SharePoint Admin role or Global Administrator role. SharePoint Modern Pages do not have a Content Editor web part, although you may want to take a look at the out of the box [Embed](https://support.office.com/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8) web part.

As for a SharePoint Framework solution for content editor, there are a few available on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=spfx+content+editor).

Comment: Thanks. I did some tests with the Embed web part, but whatever I put a link from a HTML page hosted from the same Sharepoint, then it will force it to download instead of loading it. If I try with a custom ASPX file (whatever its content) then Sharepoint says "File Not Found"?!?! I tried with both the Pages and an document library.
Regarding the SPFx solutions for content editor, my understanding is that I need to deploy them, and I cannot do it :-(

Comment: As Trevor says you need to get a site col app catalog, there is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately embedding code directly in SharePoint pages via the Content Editor web part is not supported in SharePoint online. Without permission to publish your web part, you could look into alternatives for creating your solution such as PowerApps: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerapps-and-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however PowerApps won't help here.